# regex, Python. Регулярка работает неправильно с переносом строки

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, парсер, re

Всем привет!

Есть такой код:

```
    text = '[{'EX_Text1', 'Test':'EX_Text2'}, {'SV_TEXT', 'SV_TEXT3'},'PER_TEST_3'] => DB('G_Example1', !G_Example2, !G_Example13, "Exam");'

    pattern = r"\[.+\]\s*=>\s*.*;"
    match = re.findall(pattern, text1)
```

В переменной text пример куска из файла.
Есть файл, где много похожих кусков текста и все нужно спарсить.

Все куски выглядят по шаблону: **[все символы и перенос] => все символы и перенос;**

Данная регулярка работает, но если в части до или после '=>' есть перенос строки, данная регулярка перестает забирать этот кусок. Пробовал сделать с флагом *re.S*, но тогда весь файл читается как один кусок.

Прошу подсказать, как можно исправить данное регулярное выражение.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать с флагом `re.S`, но смягчить жадность у квантификатора `.+?`

Comment: @ipatev_nn, сработало! Спасибо большое. Не хотите оставить ответ, чтоб я выбрал его?